# How can split the text form field in order to type vehicle number that consist of letters and numbers

Tags: flutter, text, flutter-textinputfield

[image]

How I can input the text in the `SplittedBox` of `TextFieldForm`,
which consist of letters and numbers?

here is my source code:

```
  Container(
 color: Colors.grey[200],
 padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
child: Column(
  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
  children: [
    Text(
   "Vehicle Number:",
    style: TextStyle(
   fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
   ),
  ),
    Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child: TextFormField(
        controller: vehicleNo,
        style: const TextStyle(
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          border: UnderlineInputBorder(
            borderRadius:
                BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
            borderSide: const BorderSide(
              width:  0,
              style: BorderStyle.none,
            ),
          ),
          fillColor: Colors.white,
          filled: true,
          //labelText: 'Vehicle Number.*',
          contentPadding:
              const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                  vertical: 10.0,
                  horizontal: 10.0),
        ),
        validator: (value) {
          if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
            return 'Please enter vehicle number';
          } else {
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I write simple class for that:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class SplitInput extends StatefulWidget {
  final String format; // example '2d 2d 3s' => 2 digits + 2 digits + 3 String(with 3 length)
  const SplitInput({required this.format});

  @override
  State<SplitInput> createState() => _SplitInputState();
}

class _SplitInputState extends State<SplitInput> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        ...cells(),
      ],
    );
  }

  cells() {
    List<Widget> cellList = [];
    final listOfCells = widget.format.split(' ');
    for (String element in listOfCells) {
      final type = element[0];
      final flex = int.parse(element.substring(1, element.length));
      final controller = TextEditingController();
      cellList.add(
        Expanded(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.black12,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
              ),
              child: TextField(
                controller: controller,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  counter: Container(),
                  focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
                  border: InputBorder.none,
                ),
                textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                keyboardType:
                    type == 's' ? TextInputType.text : TextInputType.number,
                maxLength: flex,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          flex: flex,
        ),
      );
    }
    return cellList;
  }
}
```

you can customize that.
easily you can use that like below:

```
SplitInput(format: 'd2 d2 s4 d2')
```

`d` is `digit` and `s` is `String` and after them you should write their `length` and split by space.

The output is like below:

[image]

Comment: heyy can you sugggest me how can i backspace[while erasing the inputed text] easily at once ,please give me a solution to this,bcz its a box input and user cant backspace easily... can you please let me know.....thank you:)